# read from a text file. - Python

Tags: python

My question:

For example, my text file is call 'feed.txt'. and for inside, it likes that:

```
2 # two means 'there are two matrix in this file'

3 # three means 'the below one is a 3*3 matrix'

1 8 6

3 5 7

4 9 2

4 # four means 'the below one is a 4*4 matrix'

16 3 2 13

5 10 11 8

9 6 7 12

4 15 14 1
```

There are two matrix in side this file. `[[1,8,6],[3,5,7],[4,9,2]]` and `[[16,3,2,13],[5,10,11,8],[9,6,7,12],[4,15,14,1]]`.

I want to know how can I use these two matrix in Python as a list which like

```
list_=[[1, 8, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]
```

and then I can get `sam(list_[0])=15`.

also. there are three rows in

```
list_=[[1, 8, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]
```

and I want to do the sum of each row. So I did

list_=[[1, 8, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]

for i in range(len(list_)):

```
sum_=sum(list_[i])

print(sum_)
```

but I cannot get three numbers, I only get one number, why ?

Comment: Is your question about how to read the file into lists? Or how best to build 2D arrays in python (you should read about numpy for that)?

Comment: @user823755: When I tried to do exactly what you described in your `for` loop, I got an error. Thus I think you did not paste your code accurately. Please provide code you have been using.

Comment: rest of your input is meaningless. why don't you have `4 (new line) 4` instead of just `4`?

Comment: @ahmet: I think the input has to be interpreted like this: There are `2` matrices. The first matrix has `3` rows. The next three rows belong to that matrix. Then `4` is read. So the next four rows belong to the second matrix.

Comment: @user823755 why not define the settings in JSON (http://www.json.org/), so they can be human readable and Python can interpret them into `dict`s easily.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643841/magic-squares-python

Answer (score 4):

Okay, gonna take you through this step by step. If `'file'` is your file name, try:

```
matrices = []                    # The list you'll be keeping your matrices in
with open('file') as f:
    num_matrices = int(f.readline())
    for mat_index in range(num_matrices):
        temp_matrix = []         # The list you'll keep the rows of your matrix in
        num_rows = int(f.readline())
        for row_index in range(num_rows):
            line = f.readline()
            # Split the line on whitespace, turn each element into an integer
            row = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
            temp_matrix.append(row)
        matrices.append(temp_matrix)
```

Then each of your matrices will be stored in an index of `matrices`. You can iterate through these as you like:

```
for my_matrix in matrices:
    # Do something here
    print my_matrix
```

For the second part on summing the rows, you have two options if you want this to work correctly. Either use `i` to index into a row of your list:

```
for i in range(len(my_matrix):
    total = sum(my_matrix[i])
    print(total)
```

Or use the more Pythonic way and iterate directly over your sub-lists:

```
for row in my_matrix:
    total = sum(row)
    print(total)
```

If you want to save each of these individual results for later use, you'll have to make a list for your results. Try:

```
>>> sumz = []
>>> for row in my_matrix:
    sumz.append(sum(row))

>>> sumz
[15, 15, 15]
```

Comment: sorry about my mistake, i fixed it.

Comment: but i also want to know how can i load the matrix to python from this feed.txt

Comment: @user823755 If you like the answer, please upvote and click the checkmark next to the upvote button so that it turns green. This will help others know that the answer was useful so they don't feel compelled to ask the same question in the future. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @machine yearning: As I type this, the questioner doesn't have enough reputation to up vote.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Sure but it's pretty clear to me that I answered his question thoroughly. Maybe that's what I get for answering questions like this one :)