# Read in matrix from file, make edgelist, and write edgelist to file

Tags: python, networkx

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I just need to

- read a matrix from a file into Python (that matrix has no headers/row names)
- convert it to an edgelist
- write the edgelist to file

I can do each of these separately, but I don't know how to go from the imported matrix to a graph object in networkx module for example. If I was able to convert to a networkx graph, then I can make an edgelist and write to file.

An example of a matrix to read in (its saved in .txt file)

```
1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: It seem to be some homework. However, you can start from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644529/read-from-a-text-file-python

Comment: no, not homework, i just don't know python

Comment: However, this problem seem to be related to graph theory. See related link.

Comment: Your example is 7 x 5.  What does a '1' mean in such a matrix?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i have bipartite networks, so only unlike nodes interact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need NetworkX to convert to a simple edge list:

```
adj = """1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0"""

for row,line in enumerate(adj.split('\n')):
    for col,val in enumerate(line.split(' ')):
        if val == '1':
            print row,col
```

Comment: Nice, this is a simple solution, and just what I needed

Answer (score 5):

This uses numpy to read the matrix and convert the adjacency data into a list of edges.  Then it creates a networkx Graph, and makes a plot.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Load the adjacency matrix into a numpy array.
a = np.loadtxt('matrix.txt', dtype=int)

print "a:"
print a

num_nodes = a.shape[0] + a.shape[1]

# Get the row and column coordinates where the array is 1.
rows, cols = np.where(a == 1)

# We label the nodes corresponding to the rows with integers from 0 to
# a.shape[0]-1, and we label the nodes corresponding to the columns with
# integers from a.shape[0] to a.shape[0] + a.shape[1] - 1.
# Rearranges the list of rows and columns into a list of edge tuples.
edges = zip(rows.tolist(), (cols + a.shape[0]).tolist())
print "U nodes:", np.arange(a.shape[0])
print "V nodes:", np.arange(a.shape[1]) + a.shape[0]
print "edges"
print edges

# Create a Graph object (from the networkx library).
b = nx.Graph()
b.add_nodes_from(range(num_nodes))  # This line not strictly necessry.
b.add_edges_from(edges)

# Draw the graph.  First create positions for each node. Put the U nodes
# on the left (x=1) and the V nodes on the right (x=2).
pos = dict([(k, (1, k - 0.5 * a.shape[0]))
            for k in range(a.shape[0])])
pos.update(dict([(k + a.shape[0], (2, k - 0.5 * a.shape[1]))
                  for k in range(a.shape[1])]))
nx.draw_networkx(b, pos=pos, node_color=(['c'] * a.shape[0]) + (['y'] * a.shape[1]))

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
a:
[[1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0]]
U nodes: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
V nodes: [ 7  8  9 10 11]
edges:
[(0, 7), (0, 9), (0, 11), (1, 7), (1, 9), (2, 7), (2, 9), (2, 11), (3, 9), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 11), (6, 7), (6, 9)]
```

The plot:
[image: bipartite graph]

Comment: Nice, thanks for the thorough help on this. This is great, but I accepted the below answer because it is simpler...giving an upvote to yours though

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

#read matrix without head.
a = np.loadtxt('admatrix.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=int)  #set the delimiter as you need
print "a:"
print a
print 'shape:',a.shape[0] ,"*", a.shape[1]

num_nodes = a.shape[0] + a.shape[1]

num_edge = 0
edgeSet = set()

for row in range(a.shape[0]):
    for column in range(a.shape[1]):
        if a.item(row,column) == 1 and (column,row) not in edgeSet: #get rid of repeat edge
            num_edge += 1
            edgeSet.add((row,column))

print '\nnum_edge:', num_edge
print 'edge Set:', edgeSet
print ''
for edge in edgeSet:
    print edge[0] , edge[1]
```

This code will read the adjacency matrix file delimited by comma, and output the edgelist with printing.

for instance, the adj-matrix.txt is:

```
0, 1, 0, 1
1, 0, 1, 0
0, 1, 0, 0
1, 0, 0, 0
```

The output of edgelist will be:

```
0 1
0 3
1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For reading files, you want python's `fp = open('\path\to\filename.txt')`

   [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html) has [great information](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) how to do this, and is often a great place to search for answers when you're first learning.
2. You might have a look at the [networkx](http://networkx.github.com/) package for the edge list.  They have [examples](http://networkx.github.com/examples.html) how to do this.  If you've installed setuptools, you can install it with `easy_install networkx`